# Sort lines by the number inside brakets

Tags: javascript, shell, sorting, applescript

Initial Data:

```
bla bla [200] bla bla
bla [100] bla bla
bla bla bla bla [400]
bla bla [150] bla bla
```

Desired Data:

```
bla bla bla bla [400]
bla bla [200] bla bla
bla bla [150] bla bla
bla [100] bla bla
```

Either via javascript, shell script or applescript.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Use a regular expression to extract the number in brackets from the line, and use that in `sort()`.

```
var lines = [
    'bla bla [200] bla bla',
    'bla [100] bla bla',
    'bla bla bla bla [400]',
    'bla bla [150] bla bla'
];

function getNumber(line) {
    return parseInt(line.match(/\[(\d+)\]/)[1], 10);
}
lines = lines.sort(function(a, b) {
    return getNumber(b) - getNumber(a);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use shell's `sort` with the options `-r` for "reverse" and `-g` for "general numeric", e.g.

```
$ echo "bla bla [200] bla bla
  bla [100] bla bla
  bla bla bla bla [400]
  bla bla [150] bla bla" | sort -rg
```

returns

```
bla bla bla bla [400]
bla bla [200] bla bla
bla bla [150] bla bla
bla [100] bla bla
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought rthbound's solution was neat so I tried it on my 10.6.8 and it did work. But when I changed the text a bit it breaks down.

```
echo "bla bla [200] bla bla
bla [100] bla bla asdf asdf asdf 
sdblyya bla bla bla [400] asdf sadf wer
blasa bla [150] bla bla" | sort -g
```

Gives,

```
bla [100] bla bla asdf asdf asdf 
bla bla [200] bla bla
blasa bla [150] bla bla
sdblyya bla bla bla [400] asdf sadf wer
```

So I am not sure what is going on there. Instead I tried a different approach, like this.

```
echo "bla bla [200] bla bla
bla [100] bla bla asdf asdf asdf 
sdblyya bla bla bla [400] asdf sadf wer
blasa bla [150] bla bla" | perl -ne 'print "$1:$_" if /(\d+)/' | sort -n | cut -d':' -f2
```

It pulls the numbers out and puts them in front of the sentence with a colon as a separator. Then sorts them numerically and finally removes the leading number and colon.

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

2 options:

```
sort -t'[' -k2nr file

gawk -F'[][]' '
    {x[$2] = $0} 
    END {PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_desc"; for (y in x) print x[y]}
' file
```